# Core Dumps but gdb is not able its find the exact location

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

Lets say i have an array A[10] and some other variables

And i am initializing it as

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++) //intentionally 20
    A[i]=0;
```

so when you run this **LIBRARY**, it will initialize the array without any error and access is also possible but the gdb gives core dump on some other place (In my case, it was showing memory for other variable as changed)

Why it is not giving core dump during initialization of array?

Comment: Because when you go out of bounds, it leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which sometimes might seem to work fine (until the moment it doesn't). If you have UB, then there's no point in speculating about the behavior of the rest of the program.

Comment: As for how to find such problems, consider using memory debuggers (like for example [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)), or perhaps static analysis tools which are often good at finding such problems. I think GCC also have some options to add bounds-checking at run-time.

Comment: in gcc and clang you can use address sanitizer for bounds checking:  i think you just need to add '-fsanitize=address' to compile options and  '-lasan' to linking options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN c/c++ you have no protection for running out of bounds of the array, the crash happens as soon as you access memory that does not belong to the process.
so as long as you go out of bounds and only write over your own memory on stack or in heap like other variables... the program will not crash, but the other variables will get changed, and if you change a pointer by this this might cause a future crash since the pointer then will point at some random memory address

Comment: And sometimes, when you are writing embedded or kernel code, there is no such thing as "memory that does not belong to the process", so you *never* get an access violation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of bounds error checking for PODs such as raw arrays during compile time, only during run time. You are invoking [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). That being said prefer [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to raw (C-style) arrays in C++.